# Сортировка массива объектов в алфавитном порядке Java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Имеется следующий код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of books: ");
    Books[] books = new Books[numberCheck()];
    for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
      books[i] = new Books();
      System.out.println("Enter reg.number: ");
      books[i].regNumber = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter author: ");
      books[i].author = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter name: ");
      books[i].name = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter year of publishing: ");
      books[i].yearOfPublishing = numberCheck();
      System.out.println("Enter publishing house: ");
      books[i].publishingHouse = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter number of pages: ");
      books[i].numberOfPages = numberCheck();
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    }


  }

  public static int numberCheck() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
      return sc.nextInt();
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.print("Wrong data. Enter a number: ");
      return numberCheck();
    }
  }
}
```

Class Books

```
public class Books extends Library {

  String author;
  String name;
  int yearOfPublishing;
  String publishingHouse;
  int numberOfPages;

  public Books(String regNumber, String author, String name, int yearOfPublishing,
      String publishingHouse, int numberOfPages) {
    super(regNumber);
    this.author = author;
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfPublishing = yearOfPublishing;
    this.publishingHouse = publishingHouse;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
  }
  public Books () {
    super();
  }
}
```

Class library

```
public abstract class Library {
  String regNumber;
  public Library (String regNumber) {
    this.regNumber = regNumber;
  }

  public Library() {

  }
}
```

Необходимо отсортировать по фамилии автора и вывести в алфавитном порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка - штука довольно простая. В методе мейн добавьте строку

```
Arrays.sort(books, Comparator.comparing(book -> book.author));
```

К сожалению, это наименьшая проблема вашего кода. Вы неправильно используете наследование. Книга не может быть наследником библиотеки. Запомните простое правило: между наследником и его суперклассом отношение is a, т.е. наследник является суперклассом. Например, слон и животное, где животное - супрекласс, слон - наследник. Слон является животным. Это правильное наследование. В вашем случае это библиотека и книга. Книга не является библиотекой, поэтому и наследование использовать некорреткно. В этом случае необходима агрегация. Агрегацией называется ситуация, когда один объект содержит в себе другой объект. Книга является частью библиотеки, т.е. в библиотеке хранится книга, но при этом книга - это не библиотека.
Кроме того, не преинебрегайте инкапсуляцией! Неспроста это принцип ооп. Ваши поля не должны быть доступны всем. Возможно вам это кажется мелочью, но это далеко не мелочь.

С учетом сказанного перепишем код таким образом, чтобы библиотека хранила в себе книги (агрегация) и выполняла необходимые нам действия с этими книгами.
Я использую lombok, чтобы не писать геттеры, сеттеры и прочий типичный код. Кроме того, с помощью него можно очень просто добавит в реализацию паттрен Билдер (порождающий паттерн, который я буду использовать для создания экземпляра книги). Это решит 2 проблемы: упростит создание экземпляра класса книги, одновременно проинициализировав ее поля, позволит сделать поля книги final (аннтоация @lombok.Value), ведь книга не может меняться, поэтому и разрешать изменять ее поля бессмысленно.

Кроме того, ваш метод, контролирующий пользовательский ввод, недостаточно гибкий. В этом случае хорошо использовать дженерики и лямбду в виде Function. Это упростит код.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    
    private final static Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final Library library = new Library();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < input(Integer::valueOf, "Enter number of books: "); i++) {
            library.add(Book.builder()
                    .regNumber(input(s->s, "Enter reg.number: "))
                    .author (input(s->s, "Enter author: "))
                    .name(input(s->s, "Enter name: "))
                    .yearOfPublishing(input(Integer::valueOf, "Enter year of publishing: "))
                    .publishingHouse(input(s->s, "Enter publishing house: "))
                    .numberOfPages(input(Integer::valueOf, "Enter number of pages: "))
                    .build());
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        }
        //пример использование библиотеки: выводим в консоль вче книги, отсортированные по полю Author
        library.print(() -> library.getBooks(Comparator.comparing(book -> book.getAuthor())));
        
    }

    private static <T> T input(Function<String, T> function, String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        try {
            return function.apply(SCANNER.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return input(function, "Wrong data. Try again: ");
        }
    }
    
}

@lombok.Builder
@lombok.Value
public class Book {

    private String regNumber;
    private String author;
    private String name;
    private Integer yearOfPublishing;
    private String publishingHouse;
    private Integer numberOfPages;
    
}

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Library {

    private final Map<String, Book> books = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void add(Book ... books) {
        for (Book book : books) this.books.put(book.getAuthor(), book);
    }
    
    public Optional<Book> getByRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
        return books.containsKey(registrationNumber) ? Optional.of(books.get(registrationNumber)) : Optional.empty();
    }
    
    public <T> Collection<Book> getBooks(Function <Book,T> function, Object arg) {        
        return books.values().stream()
                .filter(book-> Objects.equals(arg, function.apply(book)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    public <T> Collection<Book> getBooks(Function <Book,T> function, Comparator<Book> comparator, Object arg) {        
        return books.values().stream()
                .filter(book-> Objects.equals(arg, function.apply(book)))
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
        
    public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
        return books.values();
    }
    
    public Collection<Book> getBooks(Comparator<Book> comparator) {
        return books.values().stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    public void print(Supplier <Collection<Book>> supplier) {
        supplier.get().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    
}
```

Теперь с помощью библиотеки вы можете получать списки книг, используя любые сортировки, выводить их в консоль, искать по регистрационному номеру, а также по любому другому параметру и т.д.

Comment: Благодарю вас за исчерпывающий ответ. Спасибо большое, что разъяснили все по полочкам,и не только ответили на вопрос, но и поправили ошибки в коде в целом. Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: @Kirill не за что, удачи в изучении)